# Gmock - Check that a method is not called with a particular argument

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

There is a method with one string parameter `virtual void method(const std::string& str) = 0;`

In some cases, I need to be sure that this method is not called with a specific argument, for example, "321".

If the method is called somewhere as `ifce->method("123");` and in tests I do `EXPECT_CALL(mock, method("321")).Times(0);` then the test fails:

```
Expected arg #0: is equal to "321"
       Actual: "123"
     Expected: to be never called
       Actual: never called - saturated and active
[  FAILED  ] test.invokeMethodWithDiferentParameters (0 ms)
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `testing::NiceMock`, which ignores all uninteresting calls

```
NiceMock<MockFoo> mock;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, method("321")).Times(0);
```

Or add several expectations

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, method(_)).Times(AtLeast(1));
EXPECT_CALL(mock, method("321")).Times(0);
```

Comment: The first approach (with `NiceMock`) still leads to the same error.

Comment: But the second one works